# Derive Changing Start and End Time in Sequence using SQL

Tags: sql

Hi I have a requirement where I am getting continuous event data and i want to get start/end time for each event change.

Example Data

```
COL1    INSERT_TIME
A   2022-12-01 10:20:00.000
A   2022-12-01 10:30:00.000
A   2022-12-01 10:33:00.000
B   2022-12-01 10:34:00.000
B   2022-12-01 10:40:00.000
C   2022-12-01 10:41:00.000
C   2022-12-01 10:50:00.000
D   2022-12-01 10:55:00.000
A   2022-12-01 10:56:00.000
A   2022-12-01 11:57:00.000
A   2022-12-01 11:59:00.000
C   2022-12-01 12:00:00.000
C   2022-12-01 12:59:00.000
```

Expected Output:

```
COL1 START_TIME                 END_TIME
A    2022-12-01 10:20:00.000    2022-12-01 10:34:00.000
B    2022-12-01 10:34:00.000    2022-12-01 10:41:00.000
C    2022-12-01 10:41:00.000    2022-12-01 10:55:00.000
D    2022-12-01 10:55:00.000    2022-12-01 10:56:00.000
A    2022-12-01 10:56:00.000    2022-12-01 12:00:00.000
C    2022-12-01 12:00:00.000    NULL
```

I am trying to use Lead and compare the next and current row for identifying change. But how to dynamically group the rows in a bucket to get min/max time for populating start/end_time.

Data Prep

```
create OR REPLACE table test1
(
col1 varchar(10),
insert_time timestamp_ntz);

INSERT INTO TEST1 VALUES('A','2022-12-01 10:20:00');
INSERT INTO TEST1 VALUES('A','2022-12-01 10:30:00');
INSERT INTO TEST1 VALUES('A','2022-12-01 10:33:00');
INSERT INTO TEST1 VALUES('B','2022-12-01 10:34:00');
INSERT INTO TEST1 VALUES('B','2022-12-01 10:40:00');
INSERT INTO TEST1 VALUES('C','2022-12-01 10:41:00');
INSERT INTO TEST1 VALUES('C','2022-12-01 10:50:00');
INSERT INTO TEST1 VALUES('D','2022-12-01 10:55:00');
INSERT INTO TEST1 VALUES('A','2022-12-01 10:56:00');
INSERT INTO TEST1 VALUES('A','2022-12-01 11:57:00');
INSERT INTO TEST1 VALUES('A','2022-12-01 11:59:00');
INSERT INTO TEST1 VALUES('C','2022-12-01 12:00:00');
INSERT INTO TEST1 VALUES('C','2022-12-01 12:59:00');

;

select * from TEST1;

SELECT COL1,LEAD(COL1) OVER(ORDER BY INSERT_TIME) AS NEXT_COL1,
INSERT_TIME, LEAD(INSERT_TIME) OVER(PARTITION BY COL1 ORDER BY INSERT_TIME) AS NEXT_TIME
FROM TEST1;
```

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1**: flag the group transitions.  The first record in each group is what we want to keep.  The rest are just noise.
**Step 2**: filter out the unwanted records
**Step 3**: Do a simple LEAD() function to pick up the end time.

Finding the group changes:

```
Select col1, Insert_time,
    Case When col1<>IfNull(Lag(col1),'') Then Insert_time End
        Over (Order By Insert_time) as Start_time
From test1
```

Feed that into a filter:

```
Select * From (
    Select col1, Insert_time,
        Case When col1<>IfNull(Lag(col1),'') Then Insert_time End
            Over (Order By Insert_time) as Start_time
    From test1
Where Start_time is not null
```

Finally, pick up the End_time from the next record:

```
Select col1,Start_time,
    Lead(Start_time) Over (Order By Start_time) as End_time
 From (
    Select col1, Insert_time,
        Case When col1<>IfNull(Lag(col1),'') Then Insert_time End
            Over (Order By Insert_time) as Start_time
    From test1
Where Start_time is not null
```

...and that is it.